# Accessing structure in structure through pointer

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, structure, handle

**Brief description:**
I write something to structure through pointer but something else gets written. I work in atollic true studio 8.1, programming an STM32F415RG MCU.

The strangest thing is that even if I look in variables and expression window, I can see the same structure with different values.
[Same variable in two windows with different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ9Ds.png)

Now to elaborate a bit (I am going to simplify a lot of stuff to make it more readable).
I have my protocol handle type defined:

```
typedef struct
{
  RS485DriverHandle master_rs485;
} EscomProtocolHandle;
```

My RS485 driver handle is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
  UART_HandleTypeDef* uart_handle;
  TransceiverState transceiver_state;
  GPIO_TypeDef* dir_gpio;
  uint16_t      dir_pin;
} RS485DriverHandle;
```

I have created my protocol handle as a global variable:

```
static EscomProtocolHandle hprot1;
```

I pass it to my protocol init function which takes a pointer to handle as an argument:

```
Escom_Protocol_Init(&hprot1);
```

Init function passes it to RS485 driver init function which takes pointer to RS485 handle as an argument (this call is simplified a lot):

```
void Escom_Protocol_Init(EscomProtocolHandle* protocol_handle)
{
  RS485_Init(&protocol_handle->master_rs485)
}
```

RS485 init function sets default values:

```
void RS485_Init(RS485DriverHandle* rs485_handle, UART_HandleTypeDef* uart_handle,
                GPIO_TypeDef* dir_gpio, uint16_t dir_pin)
{
  /* default = listening */
  rs485_handle->uart_handle = uart_handle;
  rs485_handle->dir_gpio = dir_gpio;
  rs485_handle->dir_pin = dir_pin;
  ReceiverOutputEnable(rs485_handle);
  rs485_handle->transceiver_state = kReceiving;
}
```

Now if I look at the local variable **rs485_handle**, the values are set correctly. But If I look at my handle **hprot1**, the values don't match. Even though **rs485_handle**'s address matches the address of **master_rs485** member of the **hprot1** handle.
P.S.: I have not messed with the packing (#pragma pack) of any of the above mentioned structures, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Place a breakpoint at `ReceiverOutputEnable(rs485_handle);`. Check the values before the call and after. I see nothing wrong in your code so the problem can only be in this call.

Comment: Are the values for the arguments for `RS485_Init` specifically `UART_HandleTypeDef* uart_handle`, and `GPIO_TypeDef* dir_gpio` defined in a scope that's accessible outside of  `RS485_Init` and `Escom_Protocol_Init` and/or heap allocated?

Comment: Note: sometimes precedence rules messes up what I intend. To be sure, write:  `RS485_Init(&(protocol_handle->master_rs485))` (make sure the address of the right thing is taken)

Comment: Hard to say as we can't reproduce it. Likely cause is some manner of optimization. It could be that the variable just looks weird in the debugger. Are you debugging with optimization enabled or disabled?

Comment: Also, when in doubt, suspect Eclipse. It is to blame for everything bad in the world. The Eclipse debugger is notorious for being crap.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The values in `rs485_handle` and `hprot1->master_rs485` don't match before and after the call as well, even though the address of `rs485_handle` is <hprot1+25> which exactly matches the address of `hprot1->master_rs485`. Also I have tried to explicitly type `RS485_Init(&(protocol_handle->master_rs485))` with the same results.

Comment: @Joel I am not sure what you mean. The values for `uart_handle` and `dir_gpio` are not in scope of `RS485_Init` and `Escom_Protocol_Init` but that should not matter as they are passed in as pointers.

Comment: @Lundin The optimization has no effect on the result. So far the rule of thumb for me has been that I am always to blame but now it is starting to look like eclipse is playing tricks on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
There was a seemingly unrelated header file that had a structure prototype in it which was packed(1) and there was no `#pragma pack()` after the structre prototype to restore the packing to default state. Thus `RS485DriverHandle` was packed differently in different places. In both `Escom_Protocol_Init` and `RS485_Init` the address of the handle structure was the same, but the packing was different so for example the address of `GPIO_TypeDef* dir_gpio` member was 0x200000D6 in `Escom_Protocol_Init` but was 0x200000D9 in `RS485_Init`.

Comment: You got my upvote on you own answer. You did a proper debugging job as that is sometimes the obnly way to find the little bugger!